# Filter XML nodes having specific values in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

My requirement is to find all the uname from input xml where action = eSign.

To begin with, I have tried the below code, to filter the parent nodes where action does not contain eSign that is `!= eSign`

However the below code removes all the nodes and does not return any value when I add the `!=` operator  and when I replace the `!=` with `== 'eSign'` the code returns the nodes with eSign. Not able to understand what is wrong when I use `!=` operator for the code.

```
    import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import groovy.xml.XmlUtil;
    import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder;
    import groovy.xml.*;
    
    def Message processData(Message message) 
{        
//Body       
def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText(message.body)      parsed.data.'**'.findAll { it.action.text() != 'eSign' }.each { it.parent().remove(it) }     
message.body = XmlUtil.serialize(parsed)      
return message;    
 }
```

Input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DataPageRestResult>
    <responseStatus>SUCCESS</responseStatus>
    <response>
        <offset>0</offset>
        <limit>200</limit>
        <object>
            <name>doc_audit</name>
        </object>
    </response>
<data>
        <data>
            <id>40982</id>
            <timestamp>2021-09-23T10:32:28Z</timestamp>
            <uname>new.owner@dummy.com</uname>
            <action>GetDocVersion</action>   
        </data>
 <data>
            <id>20841</id>
            <timestamp>2021-08-02T21:13:08Z</timestamp>
            <uname>thomas.mark@dummy.com</uname>
            <action>eSign</action>
        </data>
 <data>
            <id>20829</id>
            <timestamp>2021-08-02T21:11:42Z</timestamp>
            <uname>Diana.Gray@dummy.com</uname>
            <action>MDWTaskCompletion</action>         
        </data>
 <data>
            <id>20834</id>
            <timestamp>2021-08-02T21:12:25Z</timestamp>
            <uname>Mark.Robin@dummy.com</uname>
            <action>eSign</action>       
        </data>
 <data>
            <id>20829</id>
            <timestamp>2021-08-02T21:11:42Z</timestamp>
            <uname>Tray.cook@dummy.com</uname>
            <action>MDWTaskCompletion</action>       
        </data>
      <data>
            <id>20830</id>
            <timestamp>2021-08-02T21:11:42Z</timestamp>
            <uname>Zen.Fest@dummy.com</uname>
            <action>eSign</action>        
        </data>
    </data>
</DataPageRestResult>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider coercing the "data" `Node` into a `Collection` to take advatage of `Collection#removeAll`.

```java
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

class Example {

    public static class Message {
        String body
    }
    
    private static final XmlParser XML_PARSER = new XmlParser()
    private static final Message EXAMPLE_MESSAGE = new Message(body: '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><DataPageRestResult><responseStatus>SUCCESS</responseStatus><response><offset>0</offset><limit>200</limit><object><name>doc_audit</name></object></response><data><data><id>40982</id><timestamp>2021-09-23T10:32:28Z</timestamp><uname>new.owner@dummy.com</uname><action>GetDocVersion</action></data><data><id>20841</id><timestamp>2021-08-02T21:13:08Z</timestamp><uname>thomas.mark@dummy.com</uname><action>eSign</action></data><data><id>20829</id><timestamp>2021-08-02T21:11:42Z</timestamp><uname>Diana.Gray@dummy.com</uname><action>MDWTaskCompletion</action></data><data><id>20834</id><timestamp>2021-08-02T21:12:25Z</timestamp><uname>Mark.Robin@dummy.com</uname><action>eSign</action></data><data><id>20829</id><timestamp>2021-08-02T21:11:42Z</timestamp><uname>Tray.cook@dummy.com</uname><action>MDWTaskCompletion</action></data><data><id>20830</id><timestamp>2021-08-02T21:11:42Z</timestamp><uname>Zen.Fest@dummy.com</uname><action>eSign</action></data></data></DataPageRestResult>''')
    
    public static Message processData(Message message) {
        def parsed = XML_PARSER.parseText(message.body)
        (parsed.'data'[0] as Collection)
            .removeAll { it."action".text() != "eSign" }
        message.body = XmlUtil.serialize(parsed)
        return message
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        println processData(EXAMPLE_MESSAGE).body
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this has worked. Thank you so much for your help and inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Message processData(Message message) {
    def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText(message.body)
    parsed.data.'**'.findAll { it.action.text() == 'eSign' }.each { it.parent().remove(it) }
    message.body = XmlUtil.serialize(parsed)
    message
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 
After modifying, I am getting an array of values in listofUnames. However how do I return it back from my code?

I am getting the error: 

No signature of method: static groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[thomas.mark@dummy.com, Mark.Robin@dummy.com, Zen.Fest@dummy.com]]

Comment: change `def Message processData(Message message) {` to `List<String> processData(Message message) {`

Comment: Not sure if your suggestion is understood correctly. 
somehow I am not able to format as code even after multiple attempts 

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    def List String processData(Message message) {
    //Body 
    def body = message.getBody();    
    def listOfUnames = new XmlParser().parseText(body).'**'.data
                       .findAll { it.action?.text() == 'eSign' }.uname*.text()
    return listOfUnames;
    }
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @justexecute my apologies, I misunderstood and have updated my answer...hope it's more helpful

Comment: Thank you. The intent is to remove the nodes which do not have **action = eSign**  
I modified with a **!=** operator in the code however the code does not return any nodes.  
`code`
      def Message processData(Message message) {
      //Body 
    def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText(message.body)
    parsed.data.'**'.findAll { it.action.text() != 'eSign' }.each { it.parent().remove(it) }
    message.body = XmlUtil.serialize(parsed)
    return message;
    }
`code`

Comment: the modified code for removing the nodes where action is not requal to eSign  

`def Message processData(Message message) {
      //Body 
    def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText(message.body)
    parsed.data.'**'.findAll { it.action.text() != 'eSign' }.each { it.parent().remove(it) }
    message.body = XmlUtil.serialize(parsed)
    return message;
    }
`